# Proof of Uniqueness of Limit of Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

### Below is the excerpt from the lecture note

Let $(M, d), (N, ρ)$ be the metric spaces, $ A \subset M $ and $ f: A \to  
 N $ be a given map.

Let $x_0 \in acc(A)$, $ b= \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}f(x) $.

proof :

Suppose $ b, b'= \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}f(x) $, and let $ \epsilon >0 $. Then 
$ \exists \delta, \delta'>0$ with

$ x \in A\setminus \{x_0\} $, $d(x,{x_0})<{\delta_0} \Rightarrow \rho(f(x),b) < \epsilon $

$ x \in A\setminus \{x_0\} $, $d(x,{x_0})<{\delta_1} \Rightarrow \rho(f(x),b') < \epsilon $

Thus 
$ x \in A\setminus \{x_0\} $, $d(x,{x_0})<min({\delta_0},{\delta_1}) \Rightarrow \rho(b,b') \le \rho(f(x),b)+ \rho(f(x),b') \lt 2\epsilon $ (*)
for $\forall \epsilon>0 $ since ${x_0} \in acc(A)$ (**)

---

Qusetion 1. Why dose the fact ${x_0} \in acc(A)$ make (*) be true?

Question 2. Why dose (**) guarantee that b=b'

Question 3. lecturer denotes it "$2\epsilon$ argument". What is it?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** The only reason that comes to mind is that $x_0 \in acc (A)$ is needed only to make sure that you may use the above limits. After all it makes no sence letting $x\to x_0$ if $x_0 \not \in acc(A)$.

**Question 2:** You have shown that $d(b,b')< 2\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Now this implies that $d(b,b') =0 \Leftrightarrow b=b'$.

**Question 3:** You could have chosen $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ such that $\rho(f(x),b)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\rho(f(x),b') <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Making $d(b,b')< \epsilon$. But since $\epsilon$ can be taken to be arbitrarily small it really doesn't matter if some number is smaller that $\epsilon$ or $2\epsilon$.